# ArcMap Geoprocessing not executing no error codes Ouput Feature Class: <empty>

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing

I am using ArcMap 10.8.2.

[image]

None of my geoprocessing tools are working suddenly. I have tried rebooting. No error codes are given, it simply doesn't complete the geoprocessing, just stays at the sand timer icon. Also keeps saying
output feature class:

I have tried different output locations in case the location was invalid, still the same result.

I am a beginner.

I am deciding if I should uninstall and reinstall the software all together but I only have a single use license through an online course I am taking and am unsure if it will allow me to redownload it after uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Close out of the application
2. Navigate to the below locations and **rename the ESRI folder**

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local

3. Relaunch ArcMap and test.

If the above doesn't help we'll have to know more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was just able to resolve it. I uninstalled and reinstalled arcmap and then, under "geoprocessing options" tab, I unchecked the box "enable" , to not allow geoprocessing to happen in the background. I think this was slowing down my computer and causing issues somehow.

Comment: Yes, there is a very huge difference when the process runs in the foreground.